# Adding a new record with the same name, with a soft deleted record

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a table named "Run".Each run has a state, corresponding to enum on the code side. 3 is "Deleted" state. If a "Run"'s state is 3, it is excluded when pulling Runs from the database.In an other saying called as soft delete.

So my problem is, when user delete(makes run's state 3) a "Run" and creates a new "Run" with a same name with a soft deleted "Run", `SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed` error appears.

Adding a new "Run" with the same name as a "Run" that has not been soft deleted  prevented by in-app validations.But it should be possible to add a new "Run" with the same name as a deleted "Run".

How can i add a new record with a same name with soft deleted record?

[image: Run table structure and a Soft Deleted record]

Comment: If SQLite supports it you can make the constraint on the combination of RunName and State combined.

Comment: Or a constraint of RunName and State=3

Comment: Soft deletes aren't deletes. They aren't a business term either, it's how developers often try to implement the actual business requirements. This implementation has several problems and one of them is that you can't easily enforce uniqueness constraints

Comment: Making combination constraint solved my problem, I combined RunName with Id instead of State. But that's the concept Thank you!

Comment: A combination constraint does not prevent the same name existing twice in the table with States 1 and 2 for example. Is this what you want?

Comment: I solved it in OnModelCreating on my Context class.

 `modelBuilder.Entity<RunDb>(entity => {`
                `entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.RunName ,e.Id }).IsUnique();`

In this way, a new run can be added with the same name as a deleted run. Adding a new run with the same name as a run with a state of 0,1 or 2 is already blocked by the validations in the application before it comes to the db side. This solved my problem, thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is that you trying to `Add` in the database same entity that all ready exist.
First solution is to change `State` prop to `3` and `Update` entity instead of `Add` if you  don't wanna that entity twice in the db.
Second solution is my code below if you want same entity in the database but with deferent `State`

```
//Take the entity you want from the database and set Status to 3
var run = db.Runs.Where(x => x.Id == 15).Select(x => new Run()
            {
                RunName = x.RunName,
                State = 3, //set to 3
                AmplificationKit = x.AmplificationKit,
                //add all other props without Id 

            }).ToList();

//Save to database new record whit the same properties , only State is changed
db.AddRange(run);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column `RunName`.

Instead use a [partial unique index](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_run_state ON tablename(RunName) WHERE State <> 3;
```

With the above index you can have any number of rows for a specific `RunName` with a `State` equal to 3, but only 1 row with `State` not equal to 3.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3df4e759031ef2b5d44d3ace5b46bf97).